# LINQ query returning objects with property value of specific subtype

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose we have 3 interfaces `IA , IB, IC` where `IB : IA , IC : IA`
And a class `TClass` with property `A` of type `IA`

Let `List<TClass> objects`

What is the LINQ query to get all the objects from the list that have `IB` as value of property `A`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var ofType = objects.Where(x => x.A is IB);
```